# Different versions of the Dependencies Support:design

Tags: java, android, gradle, dependency-injection, dependencies

I have been using the `com.android.support:design:24.2.0` of the dependency but it suggest that I'm using the different versions since I am new to dependencies I couldn't figure out the problem listed there I have tried many solution on the web but couldn't figure out it.The Screenshot is below. please help me to resolve it!

[image]

Comment: Try using `com.android.support:design:23.4.0`. And run GradleSync afterwords.

Comment: @Gotiasits I have done it but there are other 24.2.0 versions files there ! so once I changed it to that version it repeats the error!

Comment: Then you would have to listen to Gabriele Mariotti advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm using the different versions since I am new to dependencies I couldn't figure out the problem listed there

You are using different version of the same libraries.
Some of your dependencies have a transitive dependencies on the design library.

Just use:

```
./gradlew app:dependencies
```

to get the dependencies tree.
In this way you will be able to know which dependencies use a different version.

Comment: Could you please further  clarify this answer!

Comment: Where to type the command that you have given! Is there gradle cmd in Android studio?

Comment: You can use the terminal windows for example. The gradle/gradlew cmd is in the root folder.

Answer (score 0):

Search for `24.2.0` and `23.4.0` in your buildscript, or search for `com.android.support`. All dependencies starting with `com.android.support` should have the same version number to not risk runtime crashes due to incompatibilities, just as the error message suggests.

If you don't find `23.4.0` in your buildscript, run the `dependencies` task from the Gradle tool window that you find in the `help` category and search in the output for `24.2.0` and `23.4.0`, then you see which transitive dependency introduces the different version, then you might be able to decide what to do.